# Using select with 3 tables and two of them referencing the foreign keys sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have created these tables, now, say that i wanted to know how many subjects one professor is teaching at the time, how would i do it? I've tried with JOIN but i still don't know how to do it with more than two tables, since here i'd have to look into scheduler, then see professors id, and subject id, and then lookup what subjects name that id is and what professors name that id is.

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE sections
                   (id_sect INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE subjects
                   (id_subj INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, career TEXT)''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE professors
                   (id_p INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, lastname TEXT)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE scheduler
                   (id_sch INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id_sect INTEGER, id_subj INTEGER, id_p INTEGER, Day TEXT, From_time INTEGER, To_time INTEGER,
                   FOREIGN KEY (id_sect) REFERENCES sections (id_sect)
                    FOREIGN KEY (id_subj) REFERENCES subjects (id_subj),
                    FOREIGN KEY (id_p) REFERENCES professors (id_p))''')
```

Comment: Just use another join for each additional table. There's nothing different about 2 and 3 joins from 1 join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a 3-way join:

```
SELECT p.name, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT s.id_subj), 0) AS subject_count
FROM professors AS p
LEFT JOIN scheduler AS sc ON p.id_p = sc.id_p
LEFT JOIN subjects AS s ON sc.id_subj = s.id_subj
GROUP BY p.id_p
```

I've used a `LEFT JOIN` so that it will show professors who aren't teaching any subjects.

Actually, you don't even need to join with the `subjects` table, since the subject IDs are in the `scheduler` table. You don't need the subject names to count the number of subjects that a professor is teaching, the ID is enough.

```
SELECT p.name, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT sc.id_subj), 0) AS subject_count
FROM professors AS p
LEFT JOIN scheduler AS sc ON p.id_p = sc.id_p
GROUP BY p.id_p
```